# xcode 9 - How to take screenshot for itunesconnect using Simulator

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, xcode9

In xcode 8 simulator when I used to take **screenshots** they were of the right size for **itunesconnect** if there is no scaling in the simulator.

With the Xcode 9 the simulators scaling is different when it is at 100% the screenshots are not accepted at the iTunesConnect.

Maybe my LED (1080p) resolution is less than thats why I am having this problem. So on my current display how can I take screenshots with right size for itunesconnet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the debug menu uncheck Optimize Rendering for Window Size. Then screenshots will be at the device native resolution.

I recommend turning this back on afterwards because it improves performance.

Answer (score 5):

In the Simulator, **⌘S** (**File > New Screen Shot**) captures a screen shot at the native resolution for the device you're simulating, regardless of the size at which you are showing the device on your computer display.

The screen shot is saved to your desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here, It's driving me crazy. I checked the file properties and it's the right dimensions...

The DEFAULT option in iTunesConnect is for iPhone X screenshots... Click the middle one and you'll be good to go